# How to set videoView inside Fragment in android

Tags: java, android

How to set videoView inside fragment. I pushed a.mp4 file inside File Explorer. 3 Error shows 1. The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Videos. 2. The constructor MediaController(Videos) is undefined. 3. create method getWindowManager(). So please anyone help me how I will set VideoView inside Fragment.

```
    public class Videos extends Fragment {
    VideoView video_player_view;
    SurfaceView sur_view;
    MediaController media_controller;
    DisplayMetrics dm;

    public Videos() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_videos, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void getInit() {
        video_player_view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        media_controller = new MediaController(this);
        dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int height = dm.heightPixels;
        int width = dm.heightPixels;
        video_player_view.setMinimumHeight(height);
        video_player_view.setMinimumWidth(width);
        video_player_view.setMediaController(media_controller);
        video_player_view.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/a.mp4");
        video_player_view.start();  

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. In `onCreateView` change to `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_videos, container, false);         video_player_view = (VideoView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);`

2. Use `getActivity()` in

         `media_controller = new MediaController(getActivity());`

3. Use `getActivity().getWindowManager();`